# Can you help me with the limit of a function up and down bounded?

Tags: analysis, limits

> If ${2x-1\le f(x)\le x^2}$ for ${0<x<3}$.  Find $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)$.
>   How can I solve this?

Comment: The squeeze theorem seems appropriate for this question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem

Comment: ${2x-1\le f(x)\le x^2}$  ;  
$\lim_{x\to 1}{2x-1\le\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)\le \lim_{x\to 1}x^2}$   ;   
${lim_{x\to 1}x^2 = lim_{x\to 1}{2x-1} = 1}$  ;  
so, ${lim_{x\to 1}f(x) = 1}$?

Comment: Yes it's right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f(x)\le x^2$, then:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to 1} x^2 = 1.$$

On the other hand, since $f(x) \geq 2x-1$, then:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) \geq \lim_{x \to 1} 2x-1 = 1.$$

As a consequence, we get that:

$$1 \leq \lim_{x \to 1} f(x) \leq 1.$$

Then:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 1.$$

---

This is a good example for the squeeze theorem. Indeed, if $a(x) \leq f(x) \leq b(x)$, then:

$$\lim_{x \to k} a(x) \leq \lim_{x \to k} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \to k} b(x).$$

Then, if $\lim_{x \to k} a(x) = \lim_{x \to k} b(x) = q$, we can conclude that:

$$\lim_{x \to k} f(x) = q.$$

Answer (score 0):

Look at the problem in this way: you know nothing about $f(x)$ (since you're not provided with any definition of $f$) except that for every $x$ in the interval $(0,3)$, $f(x)$ is lower than $x^2$ and at the same time greater than $2x-1$. Then, how would you find the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $1$ (or any other point within the mentioned interval)?

It's simple. You just need to check the boundary functions ($x^2$ and $2x-1$) to see whether they're both having the same limit at that point or not. If so, then $f$ has to stuck with that, too, because $f$ lies between them. This is what the *Squeeze theorem* states.

You can see $$\lim_{x\to1}2x-1=1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to1}x^2=1$$ Therefore, it has to be the same for $f$, i.e., $$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=1$$